# Error_reporting not affecting the error level

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm trying to hide a deprecated warning on a site and so I've added `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);` but it's not having any effect. I've got the following test running:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
var_dump(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED, error_reporting());
```

And the `var_dump` is outputting `int(24575) int(32759)`, as you can see error_reporting isn't being set. I've also tried `error_reporting(24575);` just in case, and that didn't do anything either.

I've checked `ini_get('error_reporting');` and that also returns `32759`. Using `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);` also doesn't change the error level.

A little more info about the server: It's a VPS configured through WHM used for development purposes. This site is running on PHP 5.6 FPM. The server was upgraded this morning to Easy Apache 4 to enable PHP 7, though 5.6 was left as an option for older sites such as this one.

Does anyone know why `error_reporting` isn't changing the error level? I've tried googling this but all I get are questions on how to get errors to show or hide, nothing on why `error_reporting` isn't changing the error level.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);`

Comment: Tried that, no difference.

Comment: What does `ini_get('error_reporting')` return?

Comment: `string(5) "32759"`

Comment: Does `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);` work?

Comment: Just tried `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);` but still no joy. Haha, had the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was PHP-FPM, apparently it doesn't allow you to modify the configuration variables directly. The only place it can be changed is in the config file for PHP-FPM. I've disabled FPM for this site and it's working fine now.